# Magento 2.2.X > 2.3.0 upgrade issues

Tags: magento2, magento-upgrade, magento2.3

Today magento 2.3.0 was officially released. I tried to upgrade from 2.2.6 > 2.3.0 but failed. Tried to upgrade from 2.2.6 > 2.2.7 and it succeeded with no issues. tried again 2.2.7 > 2.3.0 and got the same error I had when I tried the upgrade from 2.2.6 > 2.3.0.

Error from Web Setup Wizzard - System Upgrade

> Command "update" failed: You are running composer with xdebug
>   enabled. This has a major impact on runtime performance. See
>    https://getcomposer.org/xdebug Loading composer repositories
>    with package information Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>    Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
>    packages.
>
> Problem 1
>    - magento/product-community-edition 2.3.0 requires magento/magento2-base 2.3.0 -> satisfiable by
>    magento/magento2-base[2.3.0].
>    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v2.8.38
>    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v4.1.4|install symfony/console v2.8.38
>    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v4.1.5|install symfony/console v2.8.38
>    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v4.1.6|install symfony/console v2.8.38
>    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v4.1.7|install symfony/console v2.8.38
>    - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.3.0 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.3.0].
>    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v4.1.8|install symfony/console v2.8.38
>    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v3.4.19|install symfony/console v4.1.4|install symfony/console v4.1.5|install
>    symfony/console v4.1.6|install symfony/console v4.1.7|install
>    symfony/console v4.1.8
>    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v4.1.1|install symfony/console v2.8.38|install symfony/console v3.4.19
>    - Installation request for sebastian/phpcpd 2.0.4 -> satisfiable by sebastian/phpcpd[2.0.4].
>    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v4.1.3|install symfony/console v2.8.38|install symfony/console v3.4.19
>    - sebastian/phpcpd 2.0.4 requires symfony/console ~2.7|^3.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.10, v2.7.11,
>    v2.7.12, v2.7.13, v2.7.14, v2.7.15, v2.7.16, v2.7.17, v2.7.18,
>    v2.7.19, v2.7.2, v2.7.20, v2.7.21, v2.7.22, v2.7.23, v2.7.24, v2.7.25,
>    v2.7.26, v2.7.27, v2.7.28, v2.7.29, v2.7.3, v2.7.30, v2.7.31, v2.7.32,
>    v2.7.33, v2.7.34, v2.7.35, v2.7.36, v2.7.37, v2.7.38, v2.7.39, v2.7.4,
>    v2.7.40, v2.7.41, v2.7.42, v2.7.43, v2.7.44, v2.7.45, v2.7.46,
>    v2.7.47, v2.7.48, v2.7.49, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.7.8, v2.7.9,
>    v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.8.10, v2.8.11, v2.8.12, v2.8.13, v2.8.14, v2.8.15,
>    v2.8.16, v2.8.17, v2.8.18, v2.8.19, v2.8.2, v2.8.20, v2.8.21, v2.8.22,
>    v2.8.23, v2.8.24, v2.8.25, v2.8.26, v2.8.27, v2.8.28, v2.8.29, v2.8.3,
>    v2.8.30, v2.8.31, v2.8.32, v2.8.33, v2.8.34, v2.8.35, v2.8.36,
>    v2.8.37, v2.8.38, v2.8.39, v2.8.4, v2.8.40, v2.8.41, v2.8.42, v2.8.43,
>    v2.8.44, v2.8.45, v2.8.46, v2.8.47, v2.8.48, v2.8.5, v2.8.6, v2.8.7,
>    v2.8.8, v2.8.9, v3.0.0, v3.0.1, v3.0.2, v3.0.3, v3.0.4, v3.0.5,
>    v3.0.6, v3.0.7, v3.0.8, v3.0.9, v3.1.0, v3.1.1, v3.1.10, v3.1.2,
>    v3.1.3, v3.1.4, v3.1.5, v3.1.6, v3.1.7, v3.1.8, v3.1.9, v3.2.0,
>    v3.2.1, v3.2.10, v3.2.11, v3.2.12, v3.2.13, v3.2.14, v3.2.2, v3.2.3,
>    v3.2.4, v3.2.5, v3.2.6, v3.2.7, v3.2.8, v3.2.9, v3.3.0, v3.3.1,
>    v3.3.10, v3.3.11, v3.3.12, v3.3.13, v3.3.14, v3.3.15, v3.3.16,
>    v3.3.17, v3.3.18, v3.3.2, v3.3.3, v3.3.4, v3.3.5, v3.3.6, v3.3.7,
>    v3.3.8, v3.3.9, v3.4.0, v3.4.1, v3.4.10, v3.4.11, v3.4.12, v3.4.13,
>    v3.4.14, v3.4.15, v3.4.16, v3.4.17, v3.4.18, v3.4.19, v3.4.2, v3.4.3,
>    v3.4.4, v3.4.5, v3.4.6, v3.4.7, v3.4.8, v3.4.9].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.0].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.1].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.10].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.11].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.12].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.13].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.14].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.15].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.16].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.17].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.18].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.19].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.2].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.20].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.21].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.22].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.23].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.24].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.25].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.26].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.27].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.28].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.29].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.3].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.30].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.31].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.32].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.33].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.34].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.35].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.36].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.37].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.38].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.39].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.4].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.40].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.41].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.42].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.43].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.44].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.45].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.46].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.47].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.48].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.49].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.5].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.6].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.7].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.8].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.7.9].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.0].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.1].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.10].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.11].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.12].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.13].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.14].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.15].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.16].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.17].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.18].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.19].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.2].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.20].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.21].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.22].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.23].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.24].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.25].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.26].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.27].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.28].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.29].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.3].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.30].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.31].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.32].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.33].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.34].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.35].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.36].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.37].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.39].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.4].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.40].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.41].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.42].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.43].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.44].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.45].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.46].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.47].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.48].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.5].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.6].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.7].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.8].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.9].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.0.0].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.0.1].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.0.2].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.0.3].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.0.4].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.0.5].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.0.6].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.0.7].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.0.8].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.0.9].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.1.0].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.1.1].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.1.10].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.1.2].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.1.3].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.1.4].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.1.5].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.1.6].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.1.7].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.1.8].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.1.9].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.2.0].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.2.1].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.2.10].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.2.11].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.2.12].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.2.13].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.2.14].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.2.2].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.2.3].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.2.4].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.2.5].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.2.6].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.2.7].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.2.8].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.2.9].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.3.0].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.3.1].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.3.10].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.3.11].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.3.12].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.3.13].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.3.14].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.3.15].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.3.16].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.3.17].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.3.18].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.3.2].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.3.3].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.3.4].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.3.5].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.3.6].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.3.7].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.3.8].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.3.9].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.4.0].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.4.1].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.4.10].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.4.11].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.4.12].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.4.13].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.4.14].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.4.15].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.4.16].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.4.17].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.4.18].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.4.2].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.4.3].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.4.4].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.4.5].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.4.6].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.4.7].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.4.8].
>    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.4.9].
>    - magento/magento2-base 2.3.0 requires symfony/console ~4.1.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.2, v4.1.3, v4.1.4,
>    v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8].
>    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v4.1.2|install symfony/console v2.8.38|install symfony/console v3.4.19

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the solution. Here are the commands to run to fix the issue:

```
composer config preferred-install dist
composer config sort-packages true
composer config prefer-stable true
composer require --dev friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer:~2.10.0 --no-update
composer require --dev sebastian/phpcpd:~3.0.0 --no-update
php -r '$autoload=json_decode(file_get_contents("composer.json"), true); $autoload["autoload"]["psr-4"]["Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\"]= "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"; file_put_contents("composer.json", json_encode($autoload, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT|JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));'
```

Comment: thanks for the useful post. In addition to these commands, I also needed to remove unused sample data modules which were creating problem in upgrade.

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1: Enable Developer Mode**

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

**Step 2: Here are few commands that you need to run before upgrading to Magento 2.3**

```
composer config preferred-install dist
composer config sort-packages true
composer config prefer-stable true
```

**Step 3: Now you need to fix your composer.json file to Magento 2.3 release**

```
composer require --dev friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer:~2.10.0 --no-update
```

**Step 4: Upgrade to Magento 2.3.0**

```
composer require --dev sebastian/phpcpd:~3.0.0 --no-update
```

**Step 5: Run the following command**

```
php -r '$autoload=json_decode(file_get_contents("composer.json"), true); $autoload["autoload"]["psr-4"]["Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\"]= "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"; file_put_contents("composer.json", json_encode($autoload, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT|JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));'
```

**Step 6: Run the Upgrade Command**

```
composer update
```

**Step 7: Upgrade Command**

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Comment: I am on php7.1, magento 2.2x, and I have followed your commands exactly as above, but I am still getting the symphony errors when trying to run composer update.

Comment: php 7.1 which version?

Comment: it  was problems with my composer.json file. . ..the fooman extension entered a line of code in there, that I had to manually remove

Answer (score 2):

FYI, this happens because some dependencies in `composer.json` need to be updated for Magento 2.3.0 before running `composer update`.  This is a side effect of adding support for PHP 7.2 and dropping support for PHP 7.0.

The full upgrade steps (and a script to ease the process) are documented [on the Magento website](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html).

Answer (score 1):

What helped for me to proceed is empty all the requirements in `require-dev`

So

```
"require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.1.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "1.5.3",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "2.2.2",
        "fabpot/php-cs-fixer": "~1.2",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.3 <=0.7.0",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "2.0.0"
    },
```

Became

```
  "require-dev": {},
```

This can be fixed later when you can proceed. Just grab the dev dependecies from the official repo and add them. Also, installing the below package can help resolve package dependencies.

```
composer require magento/composer-root-update-plugin=~1.0 --no-update
```