# Cannot upgrade from 2.2.7 to 2.3 via composer | Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.7

I want to upgrade my Magento from 2.2.7 to 2.3.0.

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.3.0 --no-update 
composer update
```

After typing this in my console i'm getting the following errors:

```
Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install magento/product-community-edition 2.3.0
    - magento/data-migration-tool 2.2.0 requires magento/framework ~101.0.0 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[101.0.7, 101.0.0, 101.0.1, 101.0.2, 101.0.3, 101.0.4, 101.0.5, 101.0.6].
    - magento/data-migration-tool 2.2.0 requires magento/framework ~101.0.0 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[101.0.7, 101.0.0, 101.0.1, 101.0.2, 101.0.3, 101.0.4, 101.0.5, 101.0.6].
    - magento/data-migration-tool 2.2.0 requires magento/framework ~101.0.0 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[101.0.7, 101.0.0, 101.0.1, 101.0.2, 101.0.3, 101.0.4, 101.0.5, 101.0.6].
    - magento/framework 101.0.1 requires colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract 1.3.4 -> satisfiable by colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract[v1.3.4].
    - magento/framework 101.0.2 requires colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract 1.3.4 -> satisfiable by colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract[v1.3.4].
    - magento/framework 101.0.3 requires colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract 1.3.4 -> satisfiable by colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract[v1.3.4].
    - magento/framework 101.0.1 requires colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract 1.3.4 -> satisfiable by colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract[v1.3.4].
    - magento/framework 101.0.2 requires colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract 1.3.4 -> satisfiable by colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract[v1.3.4].
    - magento/framework 101.0.3 requires colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract 1.3.4 -> satisfiable by colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract[v1.3.4].
    - magento/framework 101.0.0 requires colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract ~1.2.2 -> satisfiable by colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract[v1.2.2].
    - magento/framework 101.0.0 requires colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract ~1.2.2 -> satisfiable by colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract[v1.2.2].
    - magento/framework 101.0.7 requires magento/zendframework1 ~1.13.0 -> satisfiable by magento/zendframework1[1.13.0].
    - magento/framework 101.0.4 requires magento/zendframework1 ~1.13.0 -> satisfiable by magento/zendframework1[1.13.0].
    - magento/framework 101.0.5 requires magento/zendframework1 ~1.13.0 -> satisfiable by magento/zendframework1[1.13.0].
    - magento/framework 101.0.6 requires magento/zendframework1 ~1.13.0 -> satisfiable by magento/zendframework1[1.13.0].
    - magento/framework 101.0.7 requires magento/zendframework1 ~1.13.0 -> satisfiable by magento/zendframework1[1.13.0].
    - magento/framework 101.0.4 requires magento/zendframework1 ~1.13.0 -> satisfiable by magento/zendframework1[1.13.0].
    - magento/framework 101.0.5 requires magento/zendframework1 ~1.13.0 -> satisfiable by magento/zendframework1[1.13.0].
    - magento/framework 101.0.6 requires magento/zendframework1 ~1.13.0 -> satisfiable by magento/zendframework1[1.13.0].
    - magento/framework 101.0.7 requires magento/zendframework1 ~1.13.0 -> satisfiable by magento/zendframework1[1.13.0].
    - Can only install one of: colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract[v1.4.0, v1.3.4].
    - Can only install one of: colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract[v1.4.0, v1.3.4].
    - Can only install one of: colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract[v1.4.0, v1.2.2].
    - Can only install one of: magento/zendframework1[1.14.1, 1.13.0].
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.3.0 requires colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract ~1.4.0 -> satisfiable by colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract[v1.4.0].
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.3.0 requires magento/zendframework1 ~1.14.1 -> satisfiable by magento/zendframework1[1.14.1].
    - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.3.0 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.3.0].
    - Installation request for magento/data-migration-tool 2.2.0 -> satisfiable by magento/data-migration-tool[2.2.0].
```

So what to do or what is the problem?

Getting new errors after trying this: 
[upgrade magento 2.1.13 to 2.3.0](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252867/upgrade-magento-2-1-13-to-2-3-0/252870#252870)

```
'Problem 1
    - Installation request for magento/data-migration-tool 2.2.0 -> satisfiable by magento/data-migration-tool[2.2.0].
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.3.0 requires colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract ~1.4.0 -> satisfiable by colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract[v1.4.0].
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.3.0 requires colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract ~1.4.0 -> satisfiable by colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract[v1.4.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract v1.4.0
    - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.3.0 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.3.0].'
```

Comment: maybe you can use as a reference https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/251716/magento-2-2-x-2-3-0-upgrade-issues

Comment: Check this post for more information about magento 2.3 upgrade: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252867/upgrade-magento-2-1-13-to-2-3-0/252870#252870

Comment: @magefms - thanks. but this is not the solution... wont work for me....

Comment: Hi there... Getting new errors - see edited post on top of this page....

Comment: Please check you composer.json file and find 'colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract' this,remove it and then try again.

Comment: which php version are you using ?

Comment: I am using PHP 7.1.20

Comment: I don't know about `...colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract` issue.
But for the Data Migration Tool, I have upgraded mine to 2.3.0 (same version as Magento to be upgraded). I would not recommend the removal of this package, as @Marcel did, which might cause issues later on, who knows this package is needed on your system. Regards,
Ajmal

Comment: updating to 2.3 is not just updating composer. there's more you have to do

Answer (score 5):

I can also confirm that after removing the Magento Data Migration Tool I was able to upgrade from 2.2.7 to 2.3.1. Here are the steps:

bin/magento module:disable Magento_DataMigrationTool

bin/magento setup:upgrade

composer remove magento/data-migration-tool

By the way, I used the Magento recommended way for upgrading from 2.2 to 2.3: using the script: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html

Answer (score 3):

You need to change version for magento/data-migration-tool in composer.json file.

Like 
       magento/data-migration-tool : 2.2.2

```
        To

   magento/data-migration-tool : 2.3.2
```

or what your version upgrade like( 2.3.2 or 2.3.0 or 2.3.1 etc )

Answer (score 0):

After @Charul Tyadi answer i get the following error:

```
Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install magento/framework 102.0.0
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.3.0 requires magento/framework 102.0.0 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[102.0.0].
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.3.0 requires magento/framework 102.0.0 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[102.0.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install magento/framework 102.0.0|install magento/framework 102.0.0
    - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.3.0 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.3.0].
```

Comment: Solved: Magento Data Migration Tool causes error. After removing it from my composer.json it works...