# Magento 2 upgrade issues coming

Tags: magento2

I am trying to upgrade from Magento 2.2.8 to 2.3.3 and when I run the command

> composer update

then I am getting this error

- symfony/process v2.0.9 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.1.0].

What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

this issue was already addressed earlier:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/253047/55044

You have to make sure your composer.json file has correct dependencies for magento 2.3

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same problem and I already fixed it. Run this command:

```
composer config preferred-install dist
composer config sort-packages true
composer config prefer-stable true
composer require --dev friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer:~2.10.0 --no-update
composer require --dev sebastian/phpcpd:~3.0.0 --no-update
php -r '$autoload=json_decode(file_get_contents("composer.json"), true); $autoload["autoload"]["psr-4"]["Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\"]= "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"; file_put_contents("composer.json", json_encode($autoload, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT|JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));'
```